# Linq query returning null when trying to pass a column value from list object

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, c#-4.0

Linq query returning null when trying to pass a column value fetched from list objects . Is it possible to do as done in the code. Expecting answer or some suggestion.

```
var query = from p in context.ProcessStepTables
            where (p.DiagramID == diagramInfo.DiagramID)
            orderby p.ProcessNo select new{
                  DiagramProcessID = p.DiagramProcessID,
                  ProcessNo = p.ProcessNo,
                  ProcessID = p.ProcessID,
                  ProcessName = Process().Find(x => 
                           p.ProcessID == x.ProcessID).ProcessName.ToString(),
                  MakerName = Maker().Find(x=>
                           p.MakerID==x.MakerID).MakerName.ToString(),
                  Price = p.Price,
                  Note = p.Note,
                  Notice = p.Notice
            };

private List<MakerTable> Maker()
{
   List<MakerTable> pList = new List<MakerTable>();
   try
   {
       IQueryable<MakerTable> maker = (from data in context.MakerTables
                                       select data) as IQueryable<MakerTable>;
       foreach (MakerTable val in maker)
       {
          pList.Add(val);
       }
       return pList.OrderBy(x => x.MakerName).ToList();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code does it return null?

Comment: What's the message? I can see that the return value could be `null` because of some exception. It's better to remove or comment out all the `try-catch` blocks to debug it.

Comment: Sorry Query is Exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." The var query part is returning exception!

Comment: entire definition of your Maker method can be replaced by just one line i.e. `return context.MakerTables.OrderBy(x=>x.MakerName).ToList();`

Comment: Have you tried it without the 2 `.ToString()` calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because, your provider doesn't know about `.ToString()` method i.e., when you create a query in IQueryable form, it is translated into equivalent SQL query, so if you include any C# function, event a non-primitive datatype, it will throw you that error, because your query gets constructed something like below:

```
"Select s.DiagramProcessID as DiagramProcessID, ...other fields..
 from MakerTables s where something.ToString()=='anyvalue'"
```

so obviously, sql doesn't know anything about `.ToString()`.

Simply way to avoid is to, perform your custom Select, after applying `.ToList()` to your query.

When you do that or `.AsEnumerable()`, query is executed on the database and now whatever custom selection or where clause is there, is translated on the CLR

try this:

```
var query = context.ProcessStepTables
            .Where(s=>s.DiagramID == diagramInfo.DiagramID)
            .OrderBy(s=>s.ProcessNo)
            .ToList() //this will cause the query to be executed on the db
             //Now perform the selection on returned result set, now the linq
             //has to do with this dataset
            .Select(s=>new
             {
                   DiagramProcessID = s.DiagramProcessID,
                   ProcessNo = s.ProcessNo,
                   ProcessID = s.ProcessID,
                   //other items in your custom list
             });
```

and also you  can replace your Maker method with below:

```
private List<MakerTable> Maker()
{
    try
    {
       return context.MakerTables.OrderBy(x=>x.MakerName).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break into steps and check for nulls, step 1 is get the query going, then consumer needs to check for if Marker contains a valid value:

```
var query = from p in context.ProcessStepTables
            where (p.DiagramID == diagramInfo.DiagramID)
            orderby p.ProcessNo
            select new{
                        DiagramProcessID = p.DiagramProcessID,
                        ProcessNo = p.ProcessNo,
                        ProcessID = p.ProcessID,
                        ProcessName = Process().Find(x => p.ProcessID == x.ProcessID).ProcessName.ToString(),
                        Marker = context.MakerTables
                                        .OrderBy(itm => itm.MakerName)
                                        .FirstOrDefaut(itm => itm.MakerID==x.MakerID))
;
```

There is a situation where something isn't being found and the find is throwing an exception. It is better to **check for null off of the above code** on `Marker` before trying to extract a value from a property off of Marker.