# If list.Find() returns null.code returning exception

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

If list.Find() retuns null.code returning exception. is there a better way to do it. It is in reference to my previous post .

Link :  [Linq query returning null when trying to pass a column value from list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591499/linq-query-returning-null-when-trying-to-pass-a-column-value-from-list-object)

```
ProcessName = Process().Find(x => x.ProcessID == p.ProcessID).ProcessName ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Comment: No, I since it is inside a query atatement it didn't do for me. the full question is in link mentioned in my question.

Comment: Sorry I gave the wrong link ..........!!! I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to access `.ProcessName` when .Find() doesn't have anything to return:

Try this:

```
var matchingProcess = Process().Find(x => x.ProcessID == p.ProcessID);

ProcessName = matchingProcess ? matchingProcess.ProcessName : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 2):

Coalesce the results of Find. If Find returns null (i.e. your ProcessID wasn't found) then you will coalesce the null to an object of anonymous type with a single string property ProcessName. Then either your Process object or the object using the anonymous type will both have the ProcessName property and you can use it in your LINQ select from the original question.

```
ProcessName = (Process().Find(x => x.ProcessID == p.ProcessID) ?? new { ProcessName = "<unknown>" }).ProcessName;
```